# How to make a subdirectory act like a isolated domain using Virtual Host Directory and Alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I'm hosting localhost/~username/website and I have /subfolder/filename.txt

right now that reference goes to the root but I want it to not have that privilege and to go to localhost/~username/website/subfolder/filename.txt instead.

I'm trying this below but it's not working in my httpd-vhosts.conf. This is inside my

```
    Alias /~username/website "/Users/username/Sites/website"
    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/website">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up create multiple VirtualHost *:443 and :80 respectively with servernames that were different